# Extending and compositing injective field endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field. Let $\phi$, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be injective endomorphisms of $K$ satisfying $\phi=\phi_1\circ\phi_2=\phi_2\circ\phi_1$.

It is a classical result in Galois theory that $\phi$ (resp. $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$) can be extended non-uniquely to an endomorphism of $K^{\operatorname{sep}}$, which we denote by $\hat{\phi}$ (resp. $\hat{\phi}_1$, $\hat{\phi}_2$).

Since the extension is not unique, now we fix a choice of $\hat{\phi}$. The question is can we choose $\hat{\phi}_1$ and $\hat{\phi}_2$ simultaneously that satify $\hat{\phi}=\hat{\phi}_1\circ\hat{\phi}_2=\hat{\phi}_2\circ\hat{\phi}_1$?

Comment: I guess this is only an issue if neither $\phi_1$ nor $\phi_2$ is surjective, since if (say) $\phi_1$ is surjective you can just take any choice of $\hat{\phi}_1$ which will then also be surjective and define $\hat{\phi}_2=\hat{\phi}_1^{-1}\hat{\phi}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Unfortunately neither $\phi$, $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$ is surjective in the case I interested... :-(

Comment: @EricWofsey I modified my statement, but it doen't look simpler.

Comment: The requirement that $\hat{\phi}_1$ and $\hat{\phi}_2$ commute massively changes things.  There need not even exist any extensions of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ that still commute, let alone extensions that have a particular composition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There need not exist any extensions of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ that commute.  Indeed, such extensions need not even exist when talking about automorphisms of finite Galois field extensions.  In terms of group theory, the question then becomes, if $G$ is a finite group with normal subgroup $H$ and you have two elements in $G/H$ that commute, can they be lifted to elements of $G$ that commute?  The answer is no; for instance, if $G$ is the quaternion group $Q_8$ and $H=\{1,-1\}$, then the images of $i$ and $j$ in $G/H$ commute but they cannot be lifted to elements of $G$ that commute since $\pm i$ does not commute with $\pm j$ for any choices of signs.

Concretely, this gives a counterexample to your question as follows.  Take any finite Galois extension $L/k$ with Galois group $Q_8$, and let $K\subset L$ be the fixed field of the subgroup $\{1,-1\}$.  Then $Gal(K/k)\cong Q_8/\{1,-1\}$ has commuting elements $i$ and $j$ which cannot be extended to commuting elements of $Gal(L/k)$.  These are then commuting endomorphisms of $K$ that cannot be extended to commuting endomorphisms of $K^{sep}$ (since such extensions would restrict to endomorphisms of $L$).